# Discrete variables in pymoo with custom or arbitrary step length

Tags: python, optimization

I'm working with the pymoo package for Python, and I'm trying to do something simple.

I have three variables (a,b,c).

I want a to be continuous, this is trivial.

I want b to be discrete, in steps of 5, e.g. [0,5,10,...,25].

I want c to also be discrete, but logarithmically spaced, e.g. [1,10,100,1000].

When using discrete variables, I cannot seem to change the step-length to anything other than 1. I have successfully tried the following:

```py
... #snippet
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(
        n_var = 3, 
        n_obj = 1, 
        n_constr = 1, 
        xl = np.array([0,0,0]), 
        xu = np.array([1,5,3]), 
        elementwise_evaluation = True,
    )

def _evaluate(self,x,out,*args,**kwargs):
    a = x[0]                          # itself
    b = round(x[1]) * 5               # evals to 0,5,10,15,20,25
    c = [1,10,100,1000][round(x[2])]  # evals to 1,10,100,1000
...
```

However this seems like a messy approach. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Directly, restricting the search space using the steps will require quite a bit of customization of the GA.
However, you can achieve this by a rather simple mapping of your variables before evaluation:

```
class MyProblem(Problem):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            n_var = 3,
            n_obj = 1,
            n_constr = 1,
            xl = np.array([0,0,0]),
            xu = np.array([5,5,5]),
            elementwise_evaluation = True,
        )

    def _evaluate(self,x,out,*args,**kwargs):
        _a, _b, _c = x
        a = _a
        b = _b * 5
        c = 10 ** _c
```

Is this what you are trying to achieve?